# Java flyweight design pattern: failing empty map test case pre/post execution

Tags: java

I'm writing an application using the flyweight design pattern. I believe my logic to be correct in the following StringFlyweightFactory class:

```
public class StringFlyweightFactory {
    
    private static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static List<String> add(String str) {
        if (str == null) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("string cannot be null");
        }
        
        String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");   
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
            if (!map.containsKey(arr[i])) { 
                map.put(arr[i], 1);
            }
            else { 
                map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) + 1);
            }
        }
        
        return Arrays.asList(arr);
    }

    public static void release(List<String> list) {
        if (list == null) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("list cannot be null");
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { 
            if (map.get(list.get(i)) == 0) { 
                map.remove(list.get(i));
            }
            else { 
                map.put(list.get(i), map.get(list.get(i)) - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static Map<String, Integer> getEntries() { 
        return map;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, my test cases only pass up to a certain point: I continually fail a condition that tries to verify that the map returned by getEntries is empty (at the beginning and end of most test cases). For example, I fail at the assertTrue checks of this test case:

```
@Test
        void testFactoryParsesAndStoresWords0() {
            var            preActual = StringFlyweightFactory.getEntries();
            assertNotNull( preActual );
            assertTrue   ( preActual.isEmpty() );

            var cite     = "a a";
            var added    = StringFlyweightFactory.add( cite );
            var expected = List.of( "a","a" ); 
            assertEqualSets( expected, added );

            var inActual   = StringFlyweightFactory.getEntries();
            var inExpected = new MapBuilder<String,Integer>()
                    .of( "a",    2 ).build();
            assertEqualMaps( inExpected, inActual );        

            StringFlyweightFactory.release( added );

            var            postActual = StringFlyweightFactory.getEntries();
            assertNotNull( postActual );
            assertTrue   ( postActual.isEmpty() );
        }
```

For reference, the release() method is only supposed to decrement the values of each key in the map by 1, not completely clear it. So I don't believe the solution to lie there.

My question is this: Is there a way to clear my static map field variable to pass these tests, while still maintaining the data necessary to pass the rest of the test?

Comment: Why do you remove the entry when it's zero? Shouldn't you remove it when it's 1 (i.e., when it is about to go to zero)?

Comment: Oh my god - good catch. I changed that and all the test cases pass now. Thank you!!